# html5 can i use <a> include <figure> tag?

Tags: html

Can i use this?

```
<a href="">
    <figure class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <figcaption class="thumbnail-caption">...</figcaption
    </figure>
</a>
```

this syntax is ok?

all other whitespace will be preserved.

```
Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
<i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a lina
```

Comment: Yes: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: emm, why don't test it by yourself? you already have the code and you can check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you don't know, just use [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) (remember about `<!doctype html>` for html5).